# Using an object's instance as a HashMap key

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I have found similar questions, but none of them have really helped me so far (which probably means I am doing something wrong, which is why I'm here).

I have a HashMap `Map<Integer, List<Book>>` that is supposed to have a `Student`'s `ID` as the key and the list of `Book` he has in his possession as the value. Although only passing the `ID` as the key works, I feel like it isn't an object-oriented enough approach and that I should use `Student` as the key (so it'd look like so: `Map<Student, List<Book>>`). I tried to use it, but then I got a bunch of errors when I tried to return a given `Student`'s list of `Book`, most likely because the `Student` wasn't found. My professor suggested me to `@Override` Java's `hashCode` and `equals` methods, which makes sense, since that's how `HashMap` compares keys, but I haven't had success in that (I am not sure what exactly I need to compare in order to see if two `Student` are the same; supposedly, their `ID` alone should work). Here are the overridden methods:

```java
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + id;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Student other = (Student) obj;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any light you could shed on this would be extremely helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error is elsewhere. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: `if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    return true;` Why did you prefer this to `return id.equals(other.id);`?

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be in your `equals` method, provided your `id` has values outside integer caching range i.e. -128 - 127

```
 if (id != other.id) // <-- Error
        return false;
```

From your example, it seems like id is an `Integer` object

> == checks whether the references are equal, i.e. whether they point to the same object.
>
> For primitive types, == checks whether the values are equal.
>
> java.lang.Integer is a reference type. int is a primitive type.
>
> Although in case of Integer, == only works for numbers between -128
>   and 127 as JVM caches those values

You need to change it to

```
if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
```

Comment: Possible, but as those look like auto-generated methods I'd guess that id is a primitive.

Comment: As the OP has used an Integer as a key in the map, makes me believe that id is an Integer instance

Comment: `if (!id.equals(other.id)) return false;` Why did you prefer this to `return id.equals(other.id);`?

Comment: @LewBloch could work well for now, but as soon as you add more fields for comparison in your equals method, you will have to change the statement return id.equals(other.id); otherwise remaining comparison statements will not be executed. Hence, the correct form is better from code extensibility point of view

Comment: That wasn't the case here, but let's say that instead of the non-object-oriented `id` we use three name parts, we could just use: `boolean is = first.equals(other.first) && second.equals(other.second) && third.equals(other.third);`. I agree that sometimes `if` chains are better, but very few equality comparisons of value types involve more than three fields.

Comment: The OP would have to use Integer in the map generics - you can't use a primitive - it would get autoboxed. Like I say, the equals method has (almost certainly) been autogenerated, so the field must be a primitive.

Comment: @lew you forgot the null handling

Comment: @barry.. Sure, that could be the case but that's the only possible point I could figure from the current details. Let's see if the OP posts more details so that things can be more concrete. Thanks

Comment: @rahulroc No, I omitted it. My memory is fine. I was making a point about booleans, and `null` handling in there would have muddied the waters. Besides, if you're handling `null`attributes in the `equals` method you're doing it wrong. As a general rule, fields that participate in value comparisons should not be allowed to be `null`. So instead, assume I remembered `null` handling, but put it in the correct place.